# How to change settings.py variables using admin?

Tags: python, django, smtp

I'm working on a "contact us" page in `Django`. I want to allow admin to change their `smtp`,`name`,`password` and `port` in `django admin`.

So there is a table `admin_contact` which can be modified via `admin` page. The problem is that I don't know how to set EMAIL_HOST,EMAIL_PORT,EMAIL_HOST_USER and 
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD inside `settings.py` (using model `admin_contact`) which I have to set to be able to use `send_mail` method in `views.py`.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No. (you'll have to use the smtp module directly)

Answer (score 0):

This is force solution but it solved my problem.

1. Generate a file (email_config.py) with your Information (Email, Password, smtp, etc) from a Form.

**email_config.py**

```
CONFIG_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
CONFIG_EMAIL = "mail@gmail.com"
CONFIG_PASS = "******"
CONFIG_PORT = "587"
```

2. Import email_config.py from you setting.

**setting.py**

```
from email_config import CONFIG_HOST, CONFIG_EMAIL, CONFIG_PASS, CONFIG_PORT

...

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
# G-mail
EMAIL_HOST = CONFIG_HOST
EMAIL_HOST_USER = CUSTOM_EMAIL
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = CONFIG_PASS
EMAIL_PORT = CONFIG_PORT
EMAIL_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

**Test**

```
> python manage.py shell
> from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
> msg = EmailMessage("Hi, man","This is a test message",to=["juan@gmail.com"])
> msg.send()
1
```

Apache and mod_wgsi need restart after change information